# NoClassDefFoundError when running Monkey runner script

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, monkeyrunner

I am running first time **monkey runner script** in my application but i got this following error:

```
D:\android softwares\AndroidSDK\tools>monkeyrunner.bat test1.py
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/chimpchat
/ChimpChat
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.<init>(MonkeyRunnerStart
er.java:60)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter
.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.chimpchat.ChimpChat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

But i am unable to sort out this issue. Please help...

**Here is my script:**

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

device.installPackage('myfile.apk')

package = 'com.example.android.myapplication'

runComponent = 'com.example.android.myapplication/.Home'

device.startActivity(component=runComponent )

device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

result = device.takeSnapshot()

result.writeToFile('/shot1.png','png')
```

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20964), r15 has a fix which is out.