# MonkeyRunner NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/chimpchat/ChimpChat

Tags: android, sdk, noclassdeffounderror, monkeyrunner

I got an exception while try to run MonkeyRunner.bat.
I found only [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049775/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-monkey-runner-script?rq=1) but its very old and with no success.

Console line:

```
mymonkeyrunner test.py
```

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/chimpchat/ChimpChat
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.<init>(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:60)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.chimpchat.ChimpChat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to resolve it? I see chimpchat.jar in tools/lib and I tried to include it in the classpath within monkeyrunner.bat, but that didn't seem to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting the comment, I figured it out. After fixing the Chimp issue, there were more libraries that Monkeyrunner was not able to find. In the end, it seemed easier to do the following:

You probably have your `$ANDROID_SWT` set to something like `sdk_dir\tools\lib\x86_64`. Copy your `ANDROID_SWT\swt.jar` into `sdk_dir\tools\lib` and then set `$ANDROID_SWT` to `sdk_dir\tools\lib`.

After I fixed this issue, I had problems with Monkeyrunner not finding adb. For that, I had to replace the last line in monkeyrunner.bat from

`call "%java_exe%" -Xmx512m "-Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path%" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\framework -jar %jarpath% %*`

to

`call "%java_exe%" -Xmx512m "-Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path%" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\..\platform-tools -jar %jarpath% %*`

Basically, make sure that `-Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir` points to where `adb.exe` is sitting. Now it seems to be working.

Comment: How did you fix "the Chimp issue"?

Comment: I didn't have that issue. Perhaps create another question with details about your issue?